# Office 365 Connector does not show the branch name after a message sent from Jenkins to MS Teams

Tags: jenkins, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

When the Office 365 Connector triggers a build it sends from Jenkins to MS teams a new message which has the following default view (see the screenshot below).

Is there any way to add a git branch name here?
Or even better to trigger that a branch is changed?

[image: Jenkins message in MS Teams]

Answer (score 2):

You can customize using `factDefinitions` and `message`.
Refer [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/Office-365-Connector/) & [Examples](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Office-365-Connector/).

Comment: @Vadim - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?